# Example of .cabal file for fay project

Tags: haskell, fay, scotty

I have a simple web app written with scotty.
I would like to use fay to generate the front-end JS code and use shared types between the frontend and the backend.

At the moment, I run my app using `cabal run`: in my .cabal file I defined an "executable" and "build-depends" depends on `base`.
When I include "fay" and "fay-base" in "build-depends", compilation fails because `Prelude` is ambigous.

I understand that "fay-base" is supposed to replace the standard prelude, but I still do want to use the standard prelude in the backend code.

So, how should I write my .cabal file and what language extensions should I use in my .hs files so that std Prelude and fay Prelude can coexist? Is this the right approach?

I am using fay-0.20.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

- You can have `fay` as a dependency, it's a normal Haskell package and doesn't cause any clashes.
- `fay-base` doesn't replace `base`. It's Fay's version of base and can only be used with Fay code, and vice versa.
- If you want to make sure `fay-base` is pulled in as a dependency you can depend on another fay package (such as the small `fay-text` to get `fay-base` included as a transitive dependency)

You have some options on when to build your fay code:

- At program startup using [Fay's API](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fay-0.20.1.2/docs/Fay.html#v:compileFile), or [fay-builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fay-builder) which lets you specify fay options in your Cabal file (see [this blog post](http://engineering.silk.co/post/82777010096/writing-admin-interfaces-with-fay-using-fay-builder) but skip the part about custom cabal hooks!)
- On every HTTP request, useful for development. You can use the Fay API, fay-builder, yesod-fay, snaplet-fay, or happstack-fay for this.
- As a  Cabal hook with a custom `Setup.hs` (Again, bad idea)